# Can I pass variables inside a function declaration?

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

When using blocks in Objective C, it is possible to use all of the variables, that were accessible inside the function where the block was defined.

Does the same apply to JavaScript functions defined as a variable?

For example, will the `successFunction` work properly, when called from inside of `someOtherFunction`, since it was declared inside of `beforeSaveFunction`?

```
var beforeSaveFunction = function(request, response) {

    var successFunction = function(code) {
        request.object.set("sessionAuthCode",code);
        response.success();
    }

    someOtherFunction(successFunction);
}
```

---

Or will I have to do this and pass along the variables inside `someOtherFunction`:

```
var beforeSaveFunction = function(request, response) {

    var successFunction = function(code, request, response) {
        request.object.set("sessionAuthCode",code);
        response.success();
    }

    someOtherFunction(successFunction, request, response);
}
```

---

If Option 1 doesn't work, is there an easier alternative than Option 2?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Also, closures.

Comment: +1 to try it, it's even quicker to do that than to ask on this website surely

Comment: In general I would agree, however I'm developing using a framework running on a web service. At the moment, I am not sure if and how I can retrieve error messages from failed JavaScript Code, which is why I wanted to make sure, that the code works before pushing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's how JavaScript closures work. As long as a variable is in scope where the function is defined, it's in scope within the function when it's called.

See: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)